# Using the *liters* marks on E6B

Tags: e6b

See the attached picture. It is an Aero Products Research E6B Model 4. Notice the *liters* marks under *imp. gal.* and *u.s. gal.* How can I use the *liters* marks? Can I convert quantities to and from liters?

[image]

I reviewed the instructions manual. It is for a variety of E6B models and does not cover this small detail of having *liters* under *imp. gal.* or *u.s. gal.*.

Comment: Much prefer the Jepps circular computers. They don't have that slidey bit so the smaller one fits in your shirt pocket, you can use them single handed, and with a bit of practice you can do wind problems just by eyeballing it with decent accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *may be wrong* as I have a different model of E6B, which does conversions differently from yours, but based on this larger picture

[image]

It looks like you line up the black marker (on the "10" on the inner scale) with the conversion you want to do (eg "U.S. gal / liters"), and read US Gals on the outer scale and Liters on the inner. A good check is that 10 US Gallons should be about 37.9 litres.